# Is there any way to join column with LIKE in faster way MySQL?

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I want to get the rows from table `es_goodsSearch` where the column `goodsNm` 
contains any word in column named `word` in  `es_manageCleanWords` table which contains about 10,000 rows in entire table. 
So I made query in following ways.

```
SELECT * FROM es_goodsSearch g 
LEFT JOIN  es_manageCleanWords  as emc 
ON  g.goodsNm LIKE CONCAT('%', emc.word,'%');
```

The problem is query is too slow to use it on production. How can I solve this problem? 
Here is my explain results and index results of following table.

[es_goodsSearch explain image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoLnc.png)

[es_manageCleanWords explain image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIqtx.png)

[es_goodsSearch index info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O52xY.png)

[es_manageCleanWords index info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAGMI.png)

Comment: Give indexing details on the concerned tables here. Also, provide EXPLAIN statement result!

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I added explain table and index images. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your options are limited . While `LIKE 'x%'` can use an index, `LIKE '%x'` cannot.

Comment: Is there any way to solve this problem in other ways? like REGEXP

Comment: @강희명 Instead of `ON` try to use `WHERE`.
For eg: 
`WHERE  g.goodsNm LIKE CONCAT('%', emc.word,'%') OR g.goodsNm IS NULL`

Comment: @강희명 do left join based on some other field (preferably integer id)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya In es_manageCleanWords Table there is no matched information with es_goods do you mean is it possible to query like SELECT * FROM es_goodsSearch g LEFT JOIN es_manageCleanWords emc WHERE g.gododsNm LIKE CONCAT('%', emc.word,'%')?

Comment: LEFT JOIN requires atleast one column to match for. Is there no other column which can be matched directly (without using LIKE based JOIN)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya: careful, moving the `LIKE` to the `WHERE` instead of the `ON` will result in (very) different results!

Comment: Your name is Korean, so I ask whether the "words" are separated by spaces?

Comment: @RickJames Yes some words are separated by spaces. Some of data in word column is single world and some of data in word columns are complex word separated by spaces.

Comment: `LIKE` does not have a "stop at word boundary" indicator.  `REGEXP` does not handle multi-byte characters (eg Hangul) correctly.  I'm not sure about `FULLTEXT`.  Tough problem.

Comment: Back to the stated problem...  You are checking _every_ row in one table against _every_ row in another table?  You are asking "does every row have at least one 'good' word in it"?  I could understand the opposite - "which rows have 'bad' words", but that does not seem to be what you are doing?